# "object reference not set to the instance of an object" when i run the query- mssql

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please access the following link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE6oo.png)

I would like to calculate the values for each column ( Jul2015 , Aug2015. ) The formula is listed as follows .

MMMYYYY = bookrate * number of days for each activity

e.g row 1 : July2015 = 18937 *23  (from 1/7 - 23/7) ,

row 2: July2015 =20503*9  (from 23/7-31/7) ,  Aug2015 =20503*20 (1/8-20/8)

*I wrote the following code to try to cater the first row.But it turned out an error message **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** ? May anyone tell me why this message will appear

```
select * into #tempcost1 from tempcost

Declare @i int 

Set @i =1  

Declare @numofrow int 

Set @numofrow = (Select COunt(*) FROM #tempcost1)

Declare @startmonth datetime

Declare @monthdiff int 

Declare @update1 varchar(max)

Declare @month1 varchar(20)

Declare @activitysate datetime 

While (@i<=@numofrow) 

Begin

  Set @monthdiff= (Select diff_month  FROM #tempcost1 where RowNumber= @i)

  Set @activitysate = (Select activity_startdate  FROM #tempcost1 where RowNumber= @i)

  Set @month1= SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, @activitysate, 100),1,3) + 
        SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, @activitysate, 100),8,4 ) 

   if (@monthdiff = 1) 

   Begin 


   Set @update1 = 'Update #tempcost1 set ' + CAST(@month1 as varchar) + ' =(Select bookrate from #tempcost1 where Rownumber=' + cast(@i as varchar) +') ' + 'where RowNumber=' + cast(@i as varchar)

 exec(@update1)

   End 

   Set @i = @i +1 


End
```

Comment: please improve your question which also improves chances of being answered :spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum

Comment: May i know if the edited question is better now ?

Comment: I'm sure all of that could be done with a single sql statement but if you really want use a procedural approach then use a CURSOR to iterate rows.   When you've done that - and still have problems - come back with another question.

Comment: The error message doesn't sound like a sql server error. Are you executing the script from an application?

Comment: Hi Honey Badger , my script is okay . , when i debug the script line by line , i can get the right result . However, when i selected all the commands and hit 'execute', the result is not correct . I do not know why.